# Why would a simply quotient cause so much overhead?

Tags: runtime, division, fortran90, determinants

I am coding in the analytic expression for a determinant a follows:

```
  detW = &
  (one+be*(u11+u22+u33)-&
  be2*(u12sq+u13sq-u11*u22+u23sq-u11*u33-u22*u33)-&
  al2*(-(u11*u22)+u13sq*(one+three*be*u22)-six*be*u12*u13*u23+u23sq+three*be*u11*u23sq-&
  u11*u33-u22*u33-three*be*u11*u22*u33+u12sq*(one+three*be*u33))-&
  al3*(u13sq*u22-two*u12*u13*u23+u12sq*u33+u11*(u23sq-u22*u33))-&
  be3*(u13sq*u22-two*u12*u13*u23+u12sq*u33+u11*(u23sq-u22*u33))+&
  al*(u22+u33-three*be2*(u13sq*u22-two*u12*u13*u23+u12sq*u33)-&
  two*be*(u12sq+u13sq+u23sq-u22*u33)+&
  u11*(one+two*be*(u22+u33)-three*be2*(u23sq-u22*u33))))
  print*, 'detW = ', detW
  print*, 'ga3 = ', ga3
  detW = ga3/detW
  Ng = (det1*detW)**pt5
```

The true value of the determinant is the first large portion as the denominator and ga3 as the numerator. I have found that when I do not calculate this determinant my code (~176,000 lines of code total) takes around 0.07 seconds whereas calculating this determinant makes the entire program take about 2.5 seconds. Furthermore, I have found that the culprit is the line `detW = ga3/detW`. When I comment this line out, the runtime drops back down to 0.07.

It only takes this long when the value of `detW` on the `detW = ga3/detW` line is exactly 1.0. Why would this occur? Why does division by 1.0 cause the program to take 3571% times as long to run?

Comment: Not sure why, but you could put an `if` statement in there to simply make detW equal to ga3, if detW is 1, and get on with life.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the workarounds - I'm mainly curious as to why this is happening as any real world implementation of this code will almost certainly not have a unitary determinant in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the source of the slowdown was, in fact, in the `Ng = (det1*detW)**pt5` line - using `sqrt` reduces the time considerably.